# Java XML file parsing - keeps on giving null when i attempt to get a node

Tags: java, xml

I've been attempting to parse an element without any success. When i run this code, my debugging print method prints out "null", which means that the element could not be found.

The array sents is a list of sentences. Each pattern is a regex pattern. What I am trying to do is to search if a sentence matches a pattern. If it does, select a template out of the multiple templates, else create a new entry. I have not implemented the creation of a new entry because I could not get the code below to work,

BTW, the content of the node appears to be null, not the node itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sents.length; i++) {

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < categories.getLength(); i1++) {

Element root = parser.document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList categories = root.getChildNodes();
category = (Element) categories.item(i1);
pattern = category.getElementsByTagName("pattern").item(0);

if (pattern != null) {
     System.out.println(pattern.getNodeValue());
}
else {
 System.out.println("Pattern object is null.");
}

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern.getNodeValue());
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(sents[i]);

        if (matcher.matches()) { // If current sentence matches
            matches = true;
            break;
        }
}

if (matches) { // If found
    templates = category.getElementsByTagName("template");

    int chosen = Generator.generateInt(0,templates.getLength()-1); // Another class method tht generates an integer between 0 and templates.getLength()-1, note that the lower range and upper range are both inclusive.

    Node template = templates.item(chosen);

    System.out.println(template.getNodeValue());
}
}
```

The variable parser is assigned to a class XMLparser. The code of XMLparser is as such:

```
    public XMLparser(String name) {
    document = getDocument(name);
}

protected static Document getDocument(String name) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        factory.setValidating(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.parse(new InputSource(name));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void saveFile(String name) {
    try {
        //write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

        StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(name+".xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

The XML file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE categories SYSTEM "vocab.dtd">
<categories>
    <category>
        <pattern>WHAT IS YOUR NAME</pattern>
        <template>My name is JavaBot.</template>
    </category>
</categories>
```

And the dtd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT categories (category*)>
<!ELEMENT category (pattern, template*)>
<!ELEMENT pattern (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT template (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: What's `i1`? Can you produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Oh, just realized i didn't show that part. I'll do so. Thanks a lot. Also I've confirmed that the array sents DOES have content in it.

Comment: Do you get a null-pointer exception? If yes, please post the stack trace.  Otherwise what does `System.out.println(pattern.getNodeValue());` print?  Does it print "null", or just nothing (empty string)?

Comment: A little confused as to why you are looping through every item in catagories getting the whole document again and resetting catagory?

Comment: Woody: I'm trying to parse multiple sentences for a chat bot. Another note: I'm adding a condition to check if the node pattern has any value at all.

Comment: regardless, why don't you get all the nodes and itterate through them, rather than counting all the nodes, then for each node navigating the node tree again, finding all the nodes again, then selecting the one you want, when you could have selected them in the first place? Does that even compile or am I missing something?

Comment: Woody: I think you are. I need to match each sentence to every pattern, not a sentence to every pattern. In that case I would use a simple for loop, not a nested one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand how your first pice of code even compiles, let alone what it is supposed to do as you are defining catagories in a loop bounded by a variable called catagories so I must be missing something. 
However, you actual problem is that you are prining the node value of an element, which is nothing. An element can contain other nodes, but doesn't have a value. I think you really mean to print the value of the text node that is inside the element

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. However, the variable pattern is a node and not an element.

Comment: except now you changed the question to add that, so the answer doesn't make sense!

Comment: sorry for that... lol. I can give the whole code if you want, but it'll take up a lot of space, and is more likely to make everyone confused.

Comment: No problems - glad it helped, don't forget to mark answered if it did!

Comment: Wow, found a link at http://www.coderanch.com/t/125966/XML/getNodeValue-returns-null and it finally lead me to the answer of why my code does not work! Its the same thing here, so take the 25 points, Woody. :) and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way, i am giving an example from my project.. This is for a Single node

**The Xml Request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
<token></token>
<key>xxxx</key>
<secret>xxxx</secret>
</request>
```

**The Xml Response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <response>
   <token>2015fc52888d2953a30550c49d548299e8f5934d</token>
   </response>
```

**The DocumentBuilder code:**

```
public void getMToken(String xml){
        try {

                DocumentBuilderFactory odbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder odb =  odbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
                Document odoc = odb.parse(is);
                odoc.getDocumentElement().normalize ();    
                System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + odoc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                NodeList LOP = odoc.getElementsByTagName("response");

                    Node FPN =LOP.item(0);
                    if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        {

                        Element token = (Element)FPN;

                        NodeList oNameList = token.getElementsByTagName("token");
                        Element firstNameElement = (Element)oNameList.item(0);
                        NodeList textNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                        this.setToken(((Node)textNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");
                        System.out.println("token : " + ((Node)textNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                        System.out.println("#####The Parsed data#####");

                        }//end of if clause

                      }catch (SAXParseException err) {

            System.out.println (err.getMessage ());

            }catch (SAXException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace ();

            }catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace ();
            }          
        }//end of token function
```

Comment: It appears that the code is about the same... I'm not sure if this answers my question, but thanks anyway for posting your code.